# Adjectives' morphology

Tags: word-usage

Why is "extravagant" a word and "vagant" isn't?

Here is what OET has to say on "extravagant":

> late 14c., in constituciouns extravagaunt, a term in Canon Law for papal decrees not originally included or codified in the Decretals, from Medieval Latin extravagantem (nominative extravagans), present participle of extravagari "wander outside or beyond," from Latin extra "outside of" (see extra-) + vagari "wander, roam" (see vague).

"Vagant" does not display any results as it is not a word.

What gave this question away is Jorge Luis Borges in "The Library of Babel". He mentions a discovery that brought "extravagant happiness". Being that his craft rarely includes prefixes, I had this corollary (as his translator has put it) question knock on my head, which I thought would be clear by itself without additional explanations for it applies to numerous contexts.

Comment: Hello, Sara. On ELU, reasonable research is expected. Could you post the etymologies of the two words, from a source mentioned at the Help Center (eg the Online Etymology Dictionary or AHD), with an attribution and a link?

Comment: Hello Edwin. Thank you for your reply. Here is what OET has to say on "extravagant" late 14c., in constituciouns extravagaunt, a term in Canon Law for papal decrees not originally included or codified in the Decretals, from Medieval Latin extravagantem (nominative extravagans), present participle of extravagari "wander outside or beyond," from Latin extra "outside of" (see extra-) + vagari "wander, roam" (see vague). "Vagant" does not display any results as it is not a word.

Comment: I'd be pretty sure the word ***vagrant*** ultimately derives from the same Latin root as used in ***extravagant*** (L. *extra + vagari* = ‘outside’ +  ‘wander’).

Comment: FumbleFingers I really like your idea, though I still don't understand it properly. Thank you

Comment: Simple answer: because _extravagant_ was borrowed and _vagant_ wasn’t. @FumbleFingers Probably yes, at least in part. It’s not entirely certain where exactly the extra r comes from (probably influence from a different verb).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yeah, well even as I wrote *ultimately derives from the same Latin root,* it was in my mind that the *actual* derivation (into English) probably came through French or something - which I didn't attempt to follow up. For all I know even now, maybe there was a Proto-Indo-European term, and perhaps *our specific* etymology came through some route other than Latin on a sort of "parallel path" (through some linguistic community that had particular problems around enunciating the /r/ sound! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the "r" comes from "vagari", so it is known where it comes from but unknown where it went. Perhaps "extravagrant" sounds cacophonic.

Comment: @SaraDalanaj No, it doesn’t. _-(ā)ri_ is the passive infinitive ending (_vagāri_) which does not appear in the participle (_vagāns_, inflectional stem _vagānt-_). The r in _vagrant_ is a different r. Variants include versions with an extra L as well. There is a frequentative Old French verb _walcrer_ (also _waucrer_ and _wagrer_, all also written with v), which is clearly related, but has /k/ instead of /g/. It’s not known exactly how (or where) _vaguer_ and this verb got mangled together to form a participle-like form with no L, a g and an r, but they did somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extravagant** came into Middle English from Latin *extrāvagantem* (from a verb, *extravagari*) and French *extravagant* and survived to the present day (OED, "[Extravagant, adj. and n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/67142)").

*Vagant* independently came into English from the Latin *vagans* (from a verb, *vagari*) and Old French *vagant*, meaning wandering or roaming, but it did not survive into modern English (OED, "[vagant, adj](https://oed.com/view/Entry/221002).").

Sometimes when two related words come into English, one survives and the other doesn't. For instance, the adjective "melliflous," meaning eloquent or (more literally) flowing like honey, has survived into modern English, but the noun "mel" (honey) is hardly used. It's difficult to say why that happens; historical language development is arbitrary.

In this case, English listeners tend to understand *extravagant* not as *extra-* (or outside) *vagant* (as one might more recent formations like *extramarital*, outside marriage), but as its own concept. If you remove *extra-*, if people understand it at all, they may construe it as "just vagant," treating the *extra-* and *vagant* only in reference to the meanings of *extravagant* they already know:

> My parties could never be described as extravagant — so does that mean that they’re **just vagant**? ([Saturday Evening Post](https://www.saturdayeveningpost.com/2019/07/in-a-word-extravagant-wanderings/))
>
> Would you be saving for an extravagant vacation? I use the word “extravagant” carefully. If you’re in debt, you’re saving up for that true expense, a vacation, could you whittle that down to not be extravagant but **just “vagant”**? Did you see what I did there? Extra-vagant. I’m not sure if that works, but the question remains: do you pay off your debt or save money first? ([You Need a Budget](https://www.youneedabudget.com/pay-off-debt-or-save-first-there-is-a-right-answer/))

Comment: Mead-makers will, of course, scoff at the idea that **mel** is *hardly used* as we make and enjoy our [melomels](http://thehivewinery.com/html/melomel.html).

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin: more than thorough, your answer is inspiring.

Comment: @Davo I would have to taste some melomel to be certain. A bottle will do. :-)